# Injecting github information into Spring bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Am trying to get value from git hub which a has a properties file say abc.properties. i need to read value from the properties file and inject it into bean class variables

Answer (score 0):

You can bind any local property file into a bean's fields using a combination of `@PropertySource` and `@Configuration`.

For example:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/path/to/abc.properties")
public class AbcProperties {

    private String someProperty;
    private int anotherProperty;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

This assumes the file is located locally. Note that `@PropertySource` can also reference classpath relative files if they're in your project.

If you really are trying to read a file remotely from GitHub at runtime, you'll probably need a custom [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar) or consider using [Spring Cloud Config](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config) to manage external configuration.

Comment: i have a solution in baeldang, but looking out for best solution and easy understandable. i know tht its there in spring cloud config server. is there any other way

Comment: If your file is local, I would use `@PropertySource` and `@Configuration` to create a bean that holds the configuration, then you can autowire that configuration bean into the places you need it. If the file is remote, I think your best bet is a custom `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ` that reads the remote file (and handles all the failure scenarios like network timeout) to load it into the Spring environment.

Comment: hi mike, propertyplaceholderconfigure is same as @propertyResource right? my problem is ....i have a properties file in a project created 4 yrs ago, that file is uploded in git, now i need to read it into a new spring project

Comment: @Kathiresan.N They service 2 different purposes. `PropertySource` is used to bind an external file into the fields of a bean while `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is used to define strategy for resolving `${...}` placeholders when they are found in a value.

Comment: hi Mike, i understood that, but it cant help us to read file from git , for which we have to make use of only spring cloud config server. My question is i should not use this cloud config server instead i have to read a properties file in github existing project and populate into bean...if u have tht sample code , that will help.. If u say @propertySource pls share the working code. NOTE : i should get from git rpositories existing proj

Comment: i know difference, `@propertySource  @value`,does that work. but that will not help my scenario. pls check above comment and reply